# Updating Cols in google Sheets

Tags: python-3.x, google-sheets, google-api, google-sheets-api, gspread

I am trying to copy columns from one sheet to another sheet. I get the columns in response from source sheet. I need to insert them into the sheet. Since methods like insertDimension and insertRange cannot do it. I used  `request = service.spreadsheets().values().update(spreadsheetId=to_spreadsheet_id, range=range_, valueInputOption = "USER_ENTERED", body={"values": response})` but it gives me error like this :- googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1sERXk6YshuNOKi4ggp11a36uf5SGutLg7DAP5vitOoQ/values/Working%20Analysis%21G2?valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED&alt=json returned "Invalid values[1][0]: struct_value {
fields {
key: "effectiveFormat"
value {
struct_value {
fields {
key: "backgroundColor"
value {
struct_value {
fields {
key: "blue"
value {
number_value: 1.0
}
}
fields {
key: "green"
value {
number_value: 1.0
}
Its a very long text......

**AND if I use other way which is commented in the code block I get the following error**
Details: "Invalid requests[0].updateCells: Attempting to write row: 15000, beyond the last requested row of: 14999">

```
def copy_column(service, from_spreadsheet_id, to_spreadsheet_id, from_sheet='Analysis', to_sheet_id, from_column='F', from_column_till='K', to_column='G'):

    request = service.spreadsheets().get(spreadsheetId=from_spreadsheet_id, ranges=[
        from_sheet + "!" + from_column + ":" + from_column_till], includeGridData=True)

    response = request.execute()["sheets"][0]["data"][0]["rowData"]

    range_ = "Working Analysis!G2"

    print(response)

    # value_range_body = {
    #     "requests": {
    #         "insertDimension": {
    #             "range": {
    #                 "sheetId": to_sheet_id,
    #                 "dimension": "COLUMNS",
    #                 "startIndex": 6,
    #                 "endIndex": 11
    #             },
    #             "inheritFromBefore": True
    #         }
    #     }
    # }
    # request_1 = service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=to_spreadsheet_id, body=value_range_body)
    # response_1 = request_1.execute()

    # body = {
    #     "requests": {
    #         "updateCells": {
    #             "rows": response,
    #             "fields": "userEnteredFormat, userEnteredValue",
    #             # "start":{
    #             #     "sheetId": to_sheet_id,
    #             #     "rowIndex": 1,
    #             #     "columnIndex": 6
    #             # },
    #             "range": {
    #                 "sheetId": to_sheet_id,
    #                 "startRowIndex": 1,
    #                 "startColumnIndex": 6,
    #                 "endColumnIndex": 13
    #             },

    #         }
    #     }
    # }

    request = service.spreadsheets().values().update(spreadsheetId=to_spreadsheet_id,
                                                   range=range_, valueInputOption = "USER_ENTERED", body={"values": response})

    response = request.execute()

    return print('Done')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the response values from `service.spreadsheets().get()` cannot be directly used to `service.spreadsheets().values().update()`. From your commented script, I guessed that you might want to copy not only the values but also the cell format.

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```py
sheetId = "###"  # Please set the sheet ID of the sheet "Working Analysis"

request = service.spreadsheets().get(spreadsheetId=from_spreadsheet_id, ranges=[from_sheet + "!" + from_column + ":" + from_column_till], includeGridData=True)
response = request.execute()["sheets"][0]["data"][0]["rowData"]

requests = {
    "requests": [
        {
            "updateCells": {
                "start": {"sheetId": sheetId, "rowIndex": 1, "columnIndex": 6},
                "rows": response,
                "fields": "*",
            }
        }
    ]
}
request = service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=to_spreadsheet_id, body=requests)
response = request.execute()
print("Done")
```

For example, if you want to copy only the values, you can use `service.spreadsheets().values().update()` as follows.

```py
request = service.spreadsheets().values().get(spreadsheetId=from_spreadsheet_id, range=from_sheet + "!" + from_column + ":" + from_column_till)
response = request.execute()["values"]
range_ = "Working Analysis!G2"
request = service.spreadsheets().values().update(spreadsheetId=to_spreadsheet_id, range=range_, valueInputOption="USER_ENTERED", body={"values": response})
response = request.execute()
return print("Done")
```

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [Method: spreadsheets.values.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get)